# Phonegap database transaction error

Tags: android, sql, database, cordova

I have a little problem here. I try to get the last id from a database table, but it gives me an error

```
the statement callback raised an exception or statement error callback did not return false
```

The code is here:

```
function onDeviceReady(){
                var db=window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "Test", 2000000);
                db.transaction(creare_baza, eroaredb, succesdb);
                //alert("intrat");
            }
            function creare_baza(tx){
                tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS demo'); 
                tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS demo (id unique, info)");
                var ult_id=0;
                tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM demo", [], ult_id=function(tx, rez){
                    return rez.insertId;
                }, eroaredb);

                tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO demo(id, info) VALUES("+(parseInt(ult_id)+1)+", 'ceva')");
            }
            function cere(tx){
                tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM demo", [], onsucces, eroaredb);
            }

            function onsucces(tx, rezultate){
                var html="Numar de randuri = "+rezultate.rows.length;
                for(var i=0;i<rezultate.rows.length;i++){
                    html=html+"Randul "+i+" cu id="+rezultate.rows.item(i).id+" si info="+rezultate.rows.item(i).info;  
                }
                alert(html);
            }

            function eroaredb(err) {
                alert("Eroare la procesare: "+err.message);
            }

            function succesdb() {
                var db=window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "Test", 2000000);
                db.transaction(cere, eroaredb);
            }
```

And another question is how can i send a new parameter to a function that insert a new row? Like:

```
function new_row(tx, id, data){
  tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO demo (id, info) VALUES("+id+", '"+data+"')");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer for your second question,

```
SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("your_DB_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

String s="INSERT INTO demo VALUES ('"+id+"','"+data+"');";

db.execSQL(s);

db.close();
```

The above code has worked for me.